# ASP.NET : the connection is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I want to execute a query but we are facing the problem of connection string

This is my code:

```
OracleCommand _commandInvoice = new OracleCommand();
_commandInvoice.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

_commandInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("I_INVOICE_ID", strInvoiceID);
_commandInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("I_ORG_ID", ORG_ID);
_commandInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("I_ORG_NAME", strOrg_name);
_commandInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("I_PROJECT", strProject);
_commandInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("I_VENDOR_NAME", strVendor_name);
_commandInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("I_VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE", strVendorType_lookup_Code);
_commandInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("I_INVOICE_NUMBER", strInvoice_number);
_commandInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("I_INVOICE_DATE", strInvoice_date);
_commandInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("I_INVOICE_AMT", strInvoice_Amt);
_commandInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("I_OUTSTANDING_AMT", strOutstanding_Amt);
_commandInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("I_OUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT", strOutstanding_req_amt);

if (obj_Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    obj_Conn.Open();
    _commandInvoice.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

We are getting am error:

> Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: And you'll also need to **define** the **stored procedure name** so your command knows *which* stored procedure to execute! I'd recommend doing this (and setting the connection) right in the constructor: `OracleCommand _commandInvoice = new OracleCommand("storedProcedureName", obj_Conn);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the [Connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.connection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on your OracleCommand to use your obj_Conn connection, or use the relevant [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65t0yd1x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
_commandInvoice.Connection = obj_Conn;
```

Comment: Or even more simply: define it in the constructor - along with the **stored procedure name** which is also currently not being set.....